# \includegraphics[]{file}

Tags: graphics, includegraphics

I have generated a 5 page PDF file using the publish option in Matlab. I am trying to include this file using `\includegraphics[]{xxx.pdf}`, but it only includes page 1 of 5. what is the solution?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) You might want to have a look at the [`pdfpages`](https://ctan.org/pkg/pdfpages) package to include long PDF files in a document in a LaTeX document.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to include a single page of a multi-page PDF, the solution is to specify the page, that you want to include. I don't know of a specific mutli-page PDF as a MWE, hence `xxx.pdf` must be replaced:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
\includegraphics[page=3]{xxx.pdf}
\end{document}
```